# Bad performance with Guava Cache on Android

Tags: java, android, guava

We use a loading Google Guava LoadingCache for bitmaps in an Android application. In the application I am running a drawing Thread, that paints the bitmaps in the cache to a Canvas. If a specific bitmap is not in the cache, it does not get drawn so that no loading will ever block the drawing Thread.

However, the painting results in visual stuttering and the frames per second rate is not how we would like it. I nailed it down to the `getIfPresent()` method of the cache. That alone takes over 20% of the applications total CPU time. In `getIfPresent()` `LocalCache$Segment.get()` takes over 80% of the time:

[image: profiling-guava-cache.jpg]

Bear in mind, this is only a lookup of an already present bitmap. There will never happen a load in `get()`.  I figured there would be a bookkeeping overhead in `get()` for the LRU queue that decides which eviction takes place if the segment is full. But this is at least an order of magnitude slower of what a `Key-Lookup` in `LRU-LinkedHashmap.get()` would give me.

We use a cache to get fast lookups if an element is in the cache, if the lookup is slow, there is no point in caching it. I also tried `getAllPresent(a)` and `asMap()` but it gives equal performance.

Library version is: *guava-11.0.1.jar*

LoadingCache is defined as follows:

```
LoadingCache<TileKey, Bitmap> tiles = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(100).build(new CacheLoader<TileKey,Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public Bitmap load(TileKey tileKey) {
            System.out.println("Loading in " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " "
                + tileKey.x + "-" + tileKey.y);

            final File[][] tileFiles = surfaceState.mapFile.getBuilding()
                .getFloors().get(tileKey.floorid)
                .getBackground(tileKey.zoomid).getTileFiles();
            String tilePath = tileFiles[tileKey.y][tileKey.x].getAbsolutePath();

            Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tilePath, options);
            }
        });
```

**My questions are:**

- Do I use it wrong?
- Is its implementation unsuitable for Android?
- Did i miss a configuration option?
- Is this a known issue with the Cache that's being worked on?

Update:

After about 100 frames painted the CacheStats are:

```
I/System.out( 6989): CacheStats{hitCount=11992, missCount=97,
loadSuccessCount=77, loadExceptionCount=0, totalLoadTime=1402984624, evictionCount=0}
```

After that `missCount` stays basicly the same as `hitCount` increments. In this case the cache is big enough for loads to happen sparsely, but `getIfPresent()` is slow nontheless.

Comment: Please don't bold every other phrase; it was hard to read so I submitted an edit to take it out.

Comment: Thank you, simchona for editing it to make it better readable.

Comment: Could you post the results of `tiles.cacheStats()` ?

Comment: (This is probably worth sending to guava-discuss and/or filing an issue, by the way.)

Comment: Why do you use a cache for it? Wouldn't a simple array do the job as well? (Draw all items in an pre-allocated array that are not null)

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut: We would like it to buffer tiles of different backgrounds zoom levels or backgrounds. We have a complex logic that that really gains from an LRU cache. I implemented it with guava, because it is flexible and provides variable weights for varyingly expensive elements. I am happy with it but the getIfPresent() cost is unexpected.

Comment: Not sure how much that would help, but... What's the concurrency story? Can you play with the concurrencyLevel?

Comment: Louis, its not a bug. Many of the design decisions assume server-class machines, such as MESI-based cache coherency or that volatile reads / CAS are cheap if uncontended (on x86). ARM processors have very different trade-offs and are not high-performance multi-threading monsters.

Comment: Ok, besides the design decisions targeting for server machines. Out of curiosity, does a single core ARM CPU suffer from simple cache coherency problems too? Does Dalvik make use of LDREX, STREX on ARM?

Comment: I don't know enough about ARM, just bits from the Dalvik GC guys. Its best to ask the concurrency-interest group.

Comment: I wonder if this was actually caused by the now-fixed [issue 1055](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1055&can=1&q=segment&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Package%20Summary).

Comment: @LouisWasserman did you able to find out if this issue was due to bug or its better to use LRU cache or LinkedHashMap?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`CacheBuilder` was designed for server-side caching, where concurrency was a primary concern. It therefore trades off single-threaded and memory overhead in exchange for better multi-threaded behavior. Android developers should use [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html), `LinkedHashMap`, or similar where single-threaded performance and memory are the primary concerns. In the future there may be a concurrencyLevel=0 to indicate that a lightweight, non-concurrent cache is required.

Comment: I have tried concurrencyLevel=1, but it did not improve the access time. concurrencyLevel=0 leads to an error. Indeed the AtomicReferenceArray takes a significant amount of CPU time. I'll go for android.util.LruCache for now. Thanks for your comment regarding the ARM architecture and your verbose answer. I would love to see a concurrencyLevel=0 in the future.

Comment: concurrencyLevel=1 means single writer, multiple readers. That doesn't provide much of a simplification to work from. A level of 0 would indicate readers are synchronized with writes, so a synchronized version could be implemented. When I code reviewed LruCache we were still working on the Cache interface, so it was low priority to add concurrencyLevel=0 to MapMaker. Thus LruCache was born.

Comment: FYI, LruCache is also available pre-Honeycomb in the compatibility library. http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

Answer (score 3):

Android code is not always optimised the same way as it is in a JVM.  What can perform very well in Java might not perform as well in Android.  I suggest you write a very simple cache of your own. e.g. using [LinkedHashMap.removeEldestEntry()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry%28java.util.Map.Entry%29) and see how that goes.